# React component setting undefined class name

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I made a component than renders some filters and looks like this

```
import * as styles from './Search.css'
.
.
.
const Filters = (props: FiltersProps) => {
    const { state } = useContext(FilterContext)
.
.
.
    return (
        <Button
          className={styles.advancedFiltersButton + ' ' + styles.light}
          onClick={handleClear}
          kind={'tertiary'}
          data-test-id={'secondary-filters-footer-cancel'}
          noFill={true}
          disabled={(Object.values(state.filters).find(i => i.length > 0) || []).length === 0}
          aria-pressed="false"
        >
    )
```

The problem is, when I import this component in a second component I'm making, that uses Filters component, the `button` gets rendered like this.

```
    <button 
      aria-pressed="false" disabled="" 
      class="button undefined undefined DefaultTheme__button__29mtS DefaultTheme__tertiary__3cLHz DefaultTheme__no-fill__1Pw4q DefaultTheme__disabled__1khJ0"
    >
        <span class="button-children DefaultTheme__children__WfQFi">Clear all filters</span>
    </button>
```

The `button` and `DefaultTheme__*` are imported correctly (and are a third component that I didn't code), but `styles.advancedFiltersButton` and `styles.light` get rendered as `undefined`.
I checked with the React Developer Tools addon, and the styles object it's empty when rendering.

This Filters component, it's wrapped by a SearchContext component, that has a ContextProvider, and that one is wrapped in a Search component that extends from React.PureComponent, because we needed to expose a couple of methods, to access the component state. And this is how I included it in the new component

```
import Search from '@internal-repo/search-component/lib/search/Search'
.
.
.
        <Search
          ref={searchRef}
          config={searchConfig}
          executor={searchExecutor}
          value={searchState}
          onValueChange={setSearchState}
        />
.
.
.
```

And it's not just the Button component that gets the undefined styles, it's every component wrapped by the Search component.
Both projects have `css-loader` and `style-loader` as dependencies.
Oddly enough, this happens only in this new component, and I'm clueless about what maybe wrong. Specially because just some styles are not being imported.

Comment: import styles from './Search.css' - direct without * ??
I think css modules is enabled?

Comment: @Vikrant same thing. and looking at the generated code it gets imported as `var styles = require("./Search.css");`